# SBT: Add dependencies to project at runtime

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

There is sbt project declaration

```
lazy val myProject = (Project("myProject", file("someRoot"))
    enablePlugins ...
    settings (...)
```

It has taskKey that extracts some dependencies to file system.

My problem is that for the moment of loading SBT I can't determine all the dependencies, it could be done only after private Command Alias is executed

```
addCommandAlias("resolveDependencies", "; resolveDependenciesTask; TODO: update myProject dependencies and reload it")
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: I know how to execute some particular task with a new set of settings. Would that work, or you need to apply the new settings for all the existing tasks?

Comment: I can try to redesign to reload the task, should be enough in scope of single task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, disregard my comment on your question. You can use a command to modify the state of the build, so after you run it, the changes it made stay.

Something along these lines:

```
// in your build.sbt

commands += Command.command("yourCustomCommand")(state =>
  Project.extract(state).append(
    Seq(libraryDependencies += // settings you want to modify
      "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite-repl" % "0.5.7" cross CrossVersion.full),
    state))
```

Then call it with `sbt yourCustomCommand`.

The state instance you return from the command becomes the new state of the build, i.e. if you've added some dependencies, the build will see them.